# Phonegap app in jquery mobile not supported for some devices in google play

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, google-play

My phonegap android app built in jQuery Mobile does not support some devices in Google Play. Is there any way to change supported and unsupported phones in Google Play or in phonegap using config.xml?

I know for native app there is a way with Android Manifest file but for me I am working with jquery mobile and taking build in phonegap so only config file manage these types of settings.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question more closely, you want to control it from an xml file. Config.xml is probably not the place since as far as I understand it is a feature of phonegap/cordova and unlikely to have the power to specify anything outside of it. There is the Android manifest xml file however, but is seems you are strictly limited to specifying features, not models, see:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Google's inclusion and exclusion of devices would be controlled from the filters you have set there: Screen resolution, android versions and more.

For the other options that you may already know about: There is a page in the developer console in Google play for excluding phones. Go to the apk sub page of your app, and click on "Manage excluded devices". In the list item to the left, choose  "All devices" or "Supported" to see a list of phones, and then filter that list with the text input field. This presupposes that you know what phones it does not work on.

If you don't know what phones it does not work on, you could figure out a test for the proper functioning of jQuery Mobile in your app, by wrapping it inside some javascript, the code could then "phone home" to one of your servers and report what device and platform has problems. You could the use cordova's device object to gather info on the phone in question:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Another path if you have developed a paid app, is to have a free app that you ask people to download and try before they commit to buying your app. This also insulates you a bit from other incompatibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

But I want to know if can move a phone in the unsupported devices list to the supported list manually in the google play or while taking build using phonegap.

Also how google categorize the supported and unsupported list in the play store while we need the app to run in all devices.

Comment: I have added (prepended) some text with regards to xml files, and filters.

Comment: You mean to config xml in phonegap? Then what? Are they general code for this?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. Could you use more words?

Comment: Thanks for your answers,

There is an option in google play to upload multiple apks thus my problem is resolved for now